# How would you transfer data of an immutable.js object between server and client?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

Background: I want to implement a react-redux app with immutable collection as store, but I am thinking of how to transfer the immutable data between server and client.

The only possible way to solve the problem is using `JSON.stringify(ImmutableObject.toJS())`, but `toJS()` is absolutely unusable and extremely slow. However I cannot simply do the trick by `JSON.stringify(ImmutableObject)` because that would 100% break the structure. Does anyone got a nice way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends if you're using only data structures that can map directly to JSON constructs (`Map`, `List`) or not.

You say that `JSON.stringify(ImmutableObject)` would 100% break the structure - but it wouldn't have any different impact on the JSON string's structure than `JSON.stringify(ImmutableObject.toJS())`, as all immutable.js collections implement the `toJSON` method. The output of both methods should be identical (apart maybe sometimes order of keys).

If your store is an immutable.js object - or contains some - you have no other option than serializing it to JSON (using one of the two above methods) - and client-side instantiating immutable.js objects before rehydrating the store.

If you use only `Map`s and `List`s, that's fairly straightforward: `.toJSON` server-side, and `fromJS` client-side. If you use data structures such as `OrderedMap`, `Set`, `Range`, `Record`, etc... your only option is to have logic client-side that knows how to revive each piece of the state before feeding it to the redux store.

You're right that the penalty of `toJS` can be huge, but in my experience, that would be for really large collections.

Finally, there is of course the option to write you're own to/from JSON serializer/deserializer - something that would output a string like `{"type": "OrderedMap", "value": [{"key": "a", "value": 1}]}` - but I'm not sure that would be any better perf-wise, and having a store-reviving logic client-side is not that bad IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using the [transit-immutable-js](https://github.com/glenjamin/transit-immutable-js) lib.

From the [docs](https://github.com/glenjamin/transit-immutable-js#api):

*"Transit is a serialisation format which builds on top of JSON to provide a richer set of types. It is extensible, which makes it a good choice for easily providing serialisation and deserialisation capabilities for Immutable's types."*